# AFNetworking 2.0 download task in comparable 1.0?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

For compatibility issues, I'm unfortunately stuck downgrading to 1.X AFNetworking. I had this code working just fine with 2.0, but in 1.X, AFURLSessionManager of course doesn't exist anymore.

I've tried browsing through the docs, but there is very little left of 1.X. Hopefully someone out there can help me get this working in 1.X!

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFURLSessionManager *session = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL* URL;
if ([url rangeOfString:@"http"].location == NSNotFound)
{
    URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];
}
else
{
    URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSProgress *progress;
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

    return [cachesDirectoryUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    [progress removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" context:NULL];
    // done
}];

[downloadTask resume];
[progress addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];
```

Comment: The old docs are still around, you just have to compose the URL manually: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.4/

Comment: @jshier blarg, I've spent the last half hour trying to find what I need to find - there are no complete examples there. Still trying though...

Comment: @remus It's almost certainly easier to fix the "compatibility issues" with AFNetworking 2 than to do what you're trying.  Can you post a separate question regarding these issues?

Comment: @AaronBrager you're right - and I did end up doing that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an equivalent to `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` in AFNetworking 1.3, or anywhere really. To replicate the functionality in 1.3 you would start with `AFHTTPRequestOperation` or a subclass and handle the data saving yourself.

Also, your code uses the download task to copy a local file, which isn't good design. In that case just copy the final directly, perhaps using `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm working through at the moment. Considering writing it out from scratch as it may end up being less work. Re: NSFileManager, I am actually doing it that way, but clearly some of that got lost in the truncation of code for SO.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? If you don't want to create the operation manually, use the `AFHTTPClient` class, or a subclass, to build it for you. Then, in the operation's success block, write the received data to disk.

Comment: The trouble is I'm having to piece together some custom parameters in another segment for multipart/form-data. It's completely screwy and isn't building the query properly.

Comment: It's always instructive to take a look at the AFNetworking source code to see how it composes things like that. And even though you can't use it, looking at version 2's code could help as well. If your posted code was working, take a look at the code for `AFURLSessionManager`.

Comment: Sigh. Didn't get this working after all due to some other roadblocks, but thanks for the help just the same!